# How to plot frequencies vs. values in SAS (power-law style graph)?

Tags: data-visualization, sas, histogram, power-law, frequency

I have a set of counts as a response variable (anywhere from 0 to 85). I want to find the easiest way to plot count on the y-axis vs frequency of that count on the x-axis, the type of plot you see in "power law" plots. For example, I have 2 people with count = 100, 5 people with count 75, ..., 20 people with count 5.

This is really just for some exploratory data analysis. I can almost achieve the same thing by reversing the order of the y-axis is a horizontal bar chart (but I can't figure out how to reverse the y-axis).

So, any ideas about either one?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SAS, but what you're describing sounds like a histogram. There must be a built-in function to produce a histogram somewhere in SAS.

Comment: I agree with Jonathan, particularly as the question mentions a bar chart (having a squiz at Google images brings up more line graphs than bar charts).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a built-in function in `SAS` for producing a `histogram`, see `PROC UNIVARIATE` [example here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_sect069.htm).